# virtualenv, executable ./bin/python2.7 could not be run

Tags: virtualenv, python-2.7

I installed virtualenv-1.7.1.2 on python-2.7 using pip-1.0.2.
when I run the command

```
$sudo virtualenv --distribute .
```

it raises the following error

```
ERROR: The executable ./bin/python2.7 could not be run: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

can anyone help?!!